# iPhone app launch image not displayed in iPad mini

Tags: ios, objective-c, launchimage

I add the `UILaunchImages` key to the Info.plist file and use a dictionary to describe each launch image, so that i can internationalize the Launch Image, My app only support iPhone:[image]

and my `UILaunchImages` like this:
[image]

my Luanch image resource like this:
[image: my Luanch image resource like this]

every thing is ok in iPhone4s, 5, ipod, 6, 6 plus, but the launch image not display at all on iPad mini(iOS 7.0.2), did i miss something?

Comment: you are not deployed for universal application, you have set only for iPhone. You should change the "Devices: iPhone" option to "universal"

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P Hi, my app did not support for iPad, so i did not deployed for universal application, but iPhone app can be installed on iPad

Comment: Yeah, absolutely installed

Comment: are you try it in the simulator or device

Comment: yes, i try it in iPad mini device, so i can find the launch image not displayed at all

Comment: There are some targets of launch image that you have to set like iOS7.0 and later, iOS6.0 and prior, etc. Did you set these targets anywhere?

Comment: @MilanGupta i did not set these targets

Comment: @iCrany I am not sure how these target setting thing would work with your way. The way I set launch images is different then you are doing. May be you can search on google about setting targets. If you would like to follow other way please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Apps that have been designed only for iPhone may launch to a blank screen when run on an iPad. This is caused by the presence of an empty iPad specific storyboard in the app bundle as well as an iPad specific UIMainStoryboardFile key in the app's Information Property List (Info.plist) file. Both are automatically created by the various Xcode template projects if the Universal option is selected.

In Xcode, Look for a file named MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard in the file navigator. If this file is present, remove it from your project.

In your app's Information Property List

Look for a key named Main storyboard file base name (iPad) or UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad. If this key is present, remove it. You should also remove any other key suffixed with (iPad) or ~ipad.

Finally, test your app on an iPad or in the iPad simulator and verify that it behaves as expected.

Comment: thank you, i have already check this file or key in my project and Info.plist, not work for me